# Is the union of a connected set $Y$ and a clopen in its complement's subspace $X - Y$ connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $X$ be connected topological space, $Y\subset X$ be connected subspace.
Suppose $A\subset X-Y$ is clopen in subspace $X-Y$.

Is $Y\cup A$ connected?